# How can I setup dhcpd (dynamic DNS)?

Tags: 11.04, server, dns, dhcp, bind

I have a Ubuntu Server 11.04 firewall/gateway set up and I'm wondering how I can configure `isc-dhcp-server` to update `bind9` to resolve hostnames in the network.

Here is my setup:

3 computers (example):

Computer 1's hostname: `laptop`

Computer 2's hostname: `desktop`

Computer 3's hostname: `nas`

Internal domain for all hosts: `lan.example.com`

Firewall/Gateway IP: `192.168.1.1`

How can I set up the DHCP and DNS server so that `laptop.lan.example.com`, for example, will resolve correctly? Also, I've been using Webmin to set up other parts of the server, so is this possible to do with Webmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not trivial at all. This old article, however, is still quite relevant.

http://www.randombugs.com/linux/linux-isc-dhcp-server-dynamic-dns-updates-debian-ubuntu.html

Comment: I didn't follow the guide completely, but it led me in the right direction. Thank you :)